# Autotools build code and unit tests in a singularity container

Tags: slurm, autotools, singularity-container

The question: Is there a way in autotools to build my code and unit tests without running the unit tests?

I have a code base that uses autotools and running `make check` compiles the code and runs unit tests.  I have a portable singularity container that I want to build and test the code on a slurm cluster.  I am able to do something like

```
./configure MPI_LAUNCHER="srun --mpi=pmi2"
singularity exec -B ${PWD} container.sif envscript.sh "make check"
```

Which will run an environment set up script (envscript.sh) and build the code.  When it gets to the unit tests, it hangs.  I think this is because it's trying to run the `srun --mpi=pmi2` in the container and not on the host.  Is there a way to get this to work with this set up?  Can I build the library and then just build the unit tests without running them?  Then in a second step, run the tests.  I imagine something like this:

```
./configure MPI_LAUNCHER="srun --mpi=pmi2 singularity exec -B ${PWD} container.sif envscript.sh"
singularity exec -B ${PWD} container.sif envscript.sh "make buildtests"
make check
```

I don't even this this would work though because our tests are set up with the `-n` for the number of cores for each test like this

```
mpirun -n test_cores ./test.sh
```

So subbing in the srun singularity command would put the `-n` after singularity.  If anyone has any idea, please let me know.

Comment: If the tests are built inside the container, then how does it make sense to run them outside the container, supposing that you could do?  And if the tests don't run inside the container, then doesn't that suggest that the built project *generally* will not run inside the container?  I mean, that's just the kind of thing that tests are *for*.

Answer (score 0):

> The question: Is there a way in autotools to build my code and unit tests without running the unit tests?

None of [the standard makefile targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Standard-Targets) provided by Automake provide for this.

In fact, the behavior of not building certain targets until `make check` is specifically requested by the `Makefile.am` author.  Designating those targets in a `check_PROGRAMS`, `check_LIBRARIES`, *etc* variable (and not anywhere else) has that effect.  **If you modify each `check_FOO` to `noinst_FOO` then all the targets named by those variables should be built by `make` / `make all`.**  Of course, if the build system already uses `noinst_` variables for other purposes then you'll need to perform some merging.

---

**BUT YOU PROBABLY DON'T WANT TO DO THAT.**

Targets designated (only) in `check_FOO` or `noinst_FOO` variables are not installed to the system by `make install`, and often they depend on data and layout provided by the build environment.  If you're not going to run them in the build environment, then you should plan not to run them at all.

Additionally, if you're performing your build inside the container because the container is the target execution environment then it is a huge red flag that the tests are not running successfully inside the container.  There is every reason to think that the misbehavior of the tests will also manifest when you try to run the installed software for your intended purposes.  That's pretty much the point of automated testing.

On the other hand, if you're building inside the container for some kind of build environment isolation purpose, then successful testing outside the container combined with incorrect behavior of the tests inside would indicate at minimum that the container does not provide an environment adequately matched to the target execution environment.  That should undercut your confidence in the test results obtained outside.  Validation tests intended to run against the installed software are a thing, to be sure, but they are a *different* thing than build-time tests.